# MySQL Query with IN clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP and this query we want to execute :-
1: Query -

```
SELECT m.sku AS sku FROM merchant m WHERE m.sku IN ('B00TSHIWCE,B00TRPS43Y,B00PGL6W6E,B00M7D93QU,B00U2E5EPA,B00TSHE1RO,B00T687TBA,B00SYFZMSS,B00SPVDTUY,B00RZY4YZG');
```

its not showing any error and **query execute successfully** and result none.

But when we change my query like this :-

2: Query-

```
SELECT m.sku AS sku FROM merchant m WHERE m.sku IN ('B00TSHIWCE', 'B00TRPS43Y', 'B00PGL6W6E', 'B00M7D93QU', 'B00U2E5EPA', 'B00TSHE1RO', 'B00T687TBA', 'B00SYFZMSS', 'B00SPVDTUY', 'B00RZY4YZG');
```

Then its give me result.

I have one string which one we pass in my 1: Query .

```
$sku = "B00TSHIWCE,B00TRPS43Y,B00PGL6W6E,B00M7D93QU,B00U2E5EPA,B00TSHE1RO, B00T687TBA,B00SYFZMSS,B00SPVDTUY,B00RZY4YZG";
```

But MySql want string like this which one we pass in my 2: Query :-

```
    $sku1 = "'B00TSHIWCE','B00TRPS43Y','B00PGL6W6E','B00M7D93QU','B00U2E5EPA','B00TSHE1RO', 'B00T687TBA','B00SYFZMSS','B00SPVDTUY','B00RZY4YZG'";
```

This one we don't want to pass.

Any other idea How I can execute my query with this string ($sku) and got all result ?

Or

Any other suggestion / example ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use `find_in_set()` instead of `in`.  Or, format the query correctly, with multiple strings in the `in` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thx for comment but FIND_IN_SET() clause same want parameter like $sku1 but we want to use $sku.

Answer (score 0):

Use [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
create table merchant (sku varchar(50));
insert into merchant values ('B00TRPS43Y');
insert into merchant values ('FOOBARBAZ');
insert into merchant values ('B00TSHE1RO');
insert into merchant values ('BAZBARFOO');

SELECT m.sku AS sku
FROM merchant m
WHERE find_in_set(
    m.sku, 'B00TSHIWCE,B00TRPS43Y,B00PGL6W6E,B00M7D93QU,B00U2E5EPA,B00TSHE1RO,B00T687TBA,B00SYFZMSS,B00SPVDTUY,B00RZY4YZG'
);
```

Result:

```
sku
B00TRPS43Y
B00TSHE1RO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following piece of code:

```
$sku2 = str_replace(",","','",$sku);
mysql_query("select m.sku as sku from merchant m where m.sku IN   ('".$sku2."')");
```